# World War 2-era WD AGO Form 53-55

Tags: world-war-two

On the World War 2-era WD AGO Form 53-55 honorable discharge form, there is a reference in Box 33 (Decorations & Citations) which on my Dad's form has 2 lines,  1.) EAMET Ribbon and 2.) Bx Sv Star "Central Europe" What does line 2 mean? 
Thanks !!

Comment: I'm guessing this was closed becuase the answer posted below seemed obvioius (although I have to admit as a non-military person, it wasn't to me). Is there something in your question that you are still uncertain about after reading that?

Answer (score 4):

I'd guess that Bx Sv Star "Central Europe" was just shorthand for Bronze Service Star "Central Europe", where the last part was the campaign for which the Bronze Service Star was awarded.

As you're probably aware, "EAMET" was an abbreviation for "European African Middle Eastern Theater".

See [here](http://ww2tribute.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/meaning-of-go-33-wd-45-on-wwii-veterans.html)